# pyserial sending unicode string as a byte array

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, python-unicode

I'm doing some arduino project that sends and receives strings.

It sends me a string, which is a comma separated list of numbers which i save to file.
I then try to read the file and send the string back in the same way i received it.

This works fine if I do this through the arduino serial monitor, yet I can't seem to get pyserial to send/encode the string in the same way it was received.

I've tried using code like this:

```
for b in bytearray("10,20","UTF-8"):
    ser.write(str(b).encode("latin_1"))

ser.flush()
```

but haven't had any luck getting it sent through correctly.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Python 3, you can simply use:

```
ser.write("10,20".encode())
```

For Python 2, I think strings can be passed directly to `ser.write()` without encoding them.

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up getting working was this:

```
ba = bytes("10,20\n", encoding="ascii")
ser.write(ba)
```