# Sending Float Values from Python to Arduino - Data in buffer but no values read

Tags: python, arduino, serial-communication, arduino-c++

I am trying to send float values from Python on Windows to an Arduino. The first problem I encounter is that I cannot view the serial monitor when I think I am sending data from my Python script. I have read online that this is becuase only one application can manage the port at once: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/serial-communication-only-working-when-serial-monitor-is-opened/601107/12

However I have seen examples where the user is viewing the serial monitor to see data coming in over serial from Python and serial.print outs from the Arduino. So I am unsure what is the case... not being able to view the serial monitor sure does make debugging this senario hard.

My Python code:

```
import struct
import serial
import time
print('test123')
x=0.8
y=0.2

ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=1)

#print(ser)
time.sleep(3)

def sendmess():
    bin = struct.pack('ff',x,y) #Pack float value into 4 bytes
    data = ser.write(bin)

    #print(bin)
    #print(len(bin))
    #print([ "0x%02x" % b for b in bin])

    
    #ser.close()

while True:
    sendmess()
```

My Arduino Code:

```
int d = 250;
float incomingByte = 1;
void setup() {
  // initialize the serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delay(d);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  delay(d);
 // reply only when you receive data:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the incoming byte:
    d = 1000;
    float incomingByte = Serial.read();

    // say what you got:
    Serial.println(incomingByte);
    
  }
  else{
Serial.println(incomingByte);    
d = 20;
  }
}
```

I see the LED flash every second so I know the serial buffer is >0, but I cannot get any data out :(.

Thanks in advance!

Mark

I have tried examples online, but I never get any data to display in the serial monitor. Nor can I say have a pin turn HIGH when I think I am getting the data I think I have sent. But without the Serial Monitor how can I debug this?

Comment: `Serial.read();` return a byte, not a float (which is [4-byte long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)), to get a floating point number, use `float myFloat = Serial.parseFloat(SKIP_ALL, '\n');`, Read the [doc](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/parsefloat/).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you aren't able to connect more than two devices to the serial connection. However, using Python you should be able to read a response from your arduino and then print that to the python Terminal (or a file) and take a look at that.

The easiest way to do that would be to use pySerial and either `ser.read(4)` to read back 4 bytes of your float or `ser.readline()` which will look for either a '\n' which you can add to your arduino code, or a timeout. Then just print it to the python terminal with `print()`.

As for actually reading the float, `Serial.read()` will only read in the next byte in the buffer. Since a float is 4 bytes long, you need to either read the 4 bytes into an array or use `Serial.parseFloat()`

**Python Code**

```py
import struct
import serial
import time
x=0.8
y=0.2

ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=1)

#print(ser)
time.sleep(3)

def sendmess():
    bin = str(x) + str(y) #Pack float value into 4 bytes
    data = ser.write(bin.encode())
    echo = ser.readline()
    print("Echo: " + echo)
    #ser.close()

while True:
    sendmess()
```

**Arduino Code:**

```
int d = 250;
float X;
float Y;
char buffer[40];
void setup() {
  // initialize the serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delay(d);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  delay(d);
 // reply only when you receive data:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the incoming byte:
    d = 1000;
    X = Serial.parseFloat();
    Y = Serial.parseFloat();

    // say what you got:
    sprintf(buffer, "X: %f Y: %f", X, Y);
    Serial.println(buffer);
    
  }
  else{
   Serial.println(buffer);  
d = 20;
  }
}
```

Comment: `echo` doesn't give you the floating point that you think to be, you need to `struct.unpack('f', data)` to get a floating point back and you might lost the precision.

Comment: @hcheung I believe the `println()` function from the arduino library returns a human readable version of the float and not the raw data of the float itself. I updated the code to ensure it reads the entire line but the code you provided above will not find a float. You'd need to parse the incoming ascii characters with `float(echo)`. For debugging purposes, it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse, I can now see what python is sending. However it looks like it is just sending 0.00 infrequntly not 0.8 & 0.2.
Echo: 0.00
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 0.00
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 0.00
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 0.00
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 0.00
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 0.00
Echo: 
Echo:

Comment: Thanks, I can now view what Python is sending. But it looks like it is just sending 0.00 intermittanly? and not the 0.8 and 0.2 vaules I have?

Echo: 0.00
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 0.00
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 0.00
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 
Echo: 0.00

Comment: @masmith8 I modified the code above by removing the data packing in python. The `Serial.parsefloat()` function expects a string and not raw bytes. I ran it through an arduino emulator, wokwi, and it works as expected now. I also cleaned up the print statements in the arduino code so that it will respond with both X and Y in a single string.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think strings can be sent via serial without being packed into bytes? As I get this error in Python: "TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes"

Comment: @masmith8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613079/pyserial-sending-unicode-string-as-a-byte-array